Firebase real-time database truested domain rules
In my real-time firebase database rules,  I want to allow read & write only from my trusted domain website. (Example: MyWebSite.com).
This is what I've tried and didn't work:
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth.token.domain === 'trusteddomain.com'",
      ".write": "auth.token.domain === 'trusteddomain.com'"
    }
}


The auth.token contains only the information from the user's auth token, no information about the domain that request comes from. This sort of check is not possible in Firebase security rules.

@FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank for the clarification, is there is a way to auth users to the real time database using firebase function without the need to verify an email login or phone number?
